# CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, location-services

My very first app is working fine so far, if location services are allowed for it.

As soon as I disable the location services for this app in particular (Airplane mode, as well as generally disabled location services are working as expected).

[image: The Error at runtime]

The code is the following:

```
    func locationServices()->Bool{
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
        case .NotDetermined, .Restricted, .Denied:
            return false
        case .AuthorizedAlways, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            return true
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }

}
```

Called from the viewDidLoad:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    txtNotes.delegate = self
    datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()
    if (inc != nil) {
        let Dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
        Dateformatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
        navigationItem.title = Dateformatter.stringFromDate((inc?.date)!)
        datePicker.date = (inc?.date)!
        txtNotes.text = inc?.notes
        ratingControl.rating = (inc?.rating)!
        lblAccuracy.text = inc?.geoloc
        self.location = inc?.geocor
    }
    else {
        if(locationServices()){
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager!.delegate = self
        locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()

        }
        else{
            lblAccuracy.text = "Location Services Disabled"
            let alertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Location Services Disabled",
                message: "Please allow this application to use location services",
                preferredStyle: .Alert)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            let openAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .Default) { (action) in
                if let url = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
                }
            }
            alertController.addAction(openAction)
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            viewDidLoad()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I'm an idiot, I made the delegate after accessing the delegate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing a not yet initialized delegate is not a smart idea...

Initializing prior to accessing it resolved my issue.